# Show full disk usage after recovering files using Photorec to the home directory & deleting them as root

Tags: disk-usage

I selected my home directory as destination to recover some deleted files using Photorec from another partition(NTFS). During the file recovery,my file system partition ran out of space & Photorec halted.Then I deleted all of the recovered files from my home directory.
Then I got an error message "can not find or .... locate graphic driver...."(I can't recall exactly what it was) in a dialogue box on a black screen.

Then I booted to my backup OS,Linux Mint, in the file manager it showed my Ubuntu partition is completely used & 0 bytes free, then I moved some of my large video file from my home directory in Ubuntu to another partition & freed some space.

After freeing some space, I booted up Ubuntu & there was no error messages. But my system partition is  90% used.

In the disk usage analyzer,indicates that my file system has only used 23.5GB.

But disk usage analyzer  also indicates below the tool bar: used 82.5GB & available 8.3GB.

How can I gain the lost disk  space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I used Photorec as root to recover files it also created directories as the root in my home directory.Too delete those directories root privileges are essential, I really didn't hit Shift+Del to delete them only moved to trash as root.
I found all of my undeleted recovered files in /root/.local/share/Trash/files. I deleted them with Shift+Del & recovered 51.3GB of space. This thread " [deleted photorec backup files taking up disk space](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1706247)" in Ubuntu forums helped me to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a slight filesystem damage since the crash (which occurred halfway during a write action and therefore not quite without consequences).

It is quite possible that i.e. the files are removed but the harddisk space not yet marked as free.

schedule a filesystem-scan at next reboot, and reboot
(to schedule such check, open a terminal and type: sudo touch /forcefsck )

after the fsck (=filesystemcheck) you can use disk analyser again.

It is completely possible that fsck repaired some deleted files...there is a big chance then that they ended up in the /lost&found directory. They can be deleted without any problem.

Comment: Well it did not work but thank you for spending your valuable time on this problem. Anyway I've found the solution.